# SimpleCart JS shelfItem in table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, simplecart

How would I be able to make the "Add to Cart" work if I were to put the simple_cart ShelfItem in table? 
I'm still cannot find a way to make this work.
I'm using the eshopper template, which have the section id with cart items and so on. But if I were to put the simplecart javascript in the , ,  and so on, when I press the add to cart it won't work. Somebody please teach me how to use this, thanks.

Sorry I counldt find the answer or I dont know how to do it.

Edit: Add cart is working now I guess? At least able to make the "quantity" to increase, or able to empty the cart, but now the price is not updating, what did I do wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT172.jpg

```
 <section id="cart_items">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="breadcrumbs">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                  <li><a href="User/HomePage.aspx">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="active">Shopping Cart</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive cart_info">
                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="cart_menu">
                            <td class="image">Item</td>
                            <td class="description">Description</td>
                            <td class="price">Price</td>
                            <td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
                            <td class="total">SubTotal</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>


<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">

<tr>
    <td class="cart_product">      
        <img src="Images (Books)/Images/511SkrkMNCL.jpg" alt="Star Wars Character Encyclopedia" class="item_thumb" thumb="Images (Books)/Images/thumb/511SkrkMNCL.jpg" style="width: 133px; height: 168px;"/>  
     </td>

    <td class="cart_description">
        <h4 class="item_name">Star Wars Character Encyclopedia</h4>
    </td>

    <td class="cart_price">
    <span class="item_price">$35.99</span><br /> 
    </td>

    <td class="cart_quantity"> 
          <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_increment">+</a>
    <p> <input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity"/> <br>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_decrement">-</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#" onclick="simpleCart.add('name=Star Wars Character Encyclopedia','price=$35.99','image=Images (Books)/Images/thumb/511SkrkMNCL.jpg');return false;"> Add to Cart</a> 
    </td>

   <td class="cart_total"> 
    <span class="simpleCart_total"></span>

   </td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="cart_product">      
        <img src="Images (Books)/Images/81rH-DQqQOL.jpg" alt="Percy Jackson and the Olympians 5 Book " class="item_thumb" thumb="Images (Books)/Images/thumb/81rH-DQqQOL.jpg" style="width: 133px; height: 168px;"/>  
     </td>

    <td class="cart_description">
        <h4 class="item_name">Percy Jackson and the Olympians 5 Book </h4>
    </td>

    <td class="cart_price">
    <span class="item_price">$80.99</span> 
    </td>

    <td class="cart_quantity">  
    <p> <input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity"/> <br>
        <br />
        <a href="#" onclick="simpleCart.add('name=Percy Jackson and the Olympians 5 Book','price=80.99','image=Images (Books)/Images/thumb/81rH-DQqQOL.jpg');return false;"> Add to Cart</a>

    </td>

   <td class="cart_total"> 
    <span class="simpleCart_total"></span>
   </td>

</tr>



<tr>
    <td class="cart_product">      
        <img src="Images (Books)/Images/51mGJ4PmMzL.jpg" alt="Star Wars: The Jedi Path" class="item_thumb" thumb="Images (Books)/Images/thumb/51mGJ4PmMzL.jpg" style="width: 133px; height: 168px;"/>  
     </td>

    <td class="cart_description">
        <h4 class="item_name">Star Wars: The Jedi Path</h4>
    </td>

    <td class="cart_price">
    <span class="item_price">$30.99</span> 
    </td>

    <td class="cart_quantity">  
    <p> <input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity"/> <br>
        <br />
        <a href="#" onclick="simpleCart.add('name=Star Wars: The Jedi Path','price=30.99','image=Images (Books)/Images/thumb/51mGJ4PmMzL.jpg');return false;"> Add to Cart</a>

    </td>

   <td class="cart_total"> 
    <span class="simpleCart_total"></span>
   </td>

</tr>


<tr>
    <td class="cart_product">      
     <img src="Images (Books)/Images/81cm6ZST7tL.jpg" alt="The Return of Nagash (The End Times)" class="item_thumb" thumb="Images (Books)/Images/thumb/81cm6ZST7tL.jpg" style="width: 133px; height: 168px;"/>  
     </td>

    <td class="cart_description">
        <h4 class="item_name">The Return of Nagash (The End Times)</h4>
    </td>

    <td class="cart_price">
    <span class="item_price">$50.99</span> 
    </td>

    <td class="cart_quantity">  
    <p> <input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity"/> <br>
        <br />
        <a href="#" onclick="simpleCart.add('name=The Return of Nagash (The End Times)','price=50.99','image=Images (Books)/Images/thumb/81cm6ZST7tL.jpg');return false;"> Add to Cart</a>

    </td>

   <td class="cart_total"> 
    <span class="simpleCart_total"></span>
   </td>

</tr>


<tr>
    <td class="cart_product">      
        <img src="Images (Books)/Images/51m3gTdOteL.jpg" alt="Star Wars: Darth Vader and the Ghost Prison" class="item_thumb" thumb="Images (Books)/Images/thumb/51m3gTdOteL.jpg" style="width: 133px; height: 168px;"/>  
     </td>

    <td class="cart_description">
        <h4 class="item_name">Star Wars: Darth Vader and the Ghost Prison</h4>
    </td>

    <td class="cart_price">
    <span class="item_price">$65.99</span> 
    </td>

    <td class="cart_quantity">  
   <p> <input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity"/> <br>
        <br />
        <a href="#" onclick="simpleCart.add('name=Star Wars: Darth Vader and the Ghost Prison<','price=65.99','image=Images (Books)/Images/thumb/51m3gTdOteL.jpg');return false;"> Add to Cart</a>

    </td>

   <td class="cart_total"> 
    <span class="simpleCart_total"></span>


   </td>

</tr>


                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section> <!--/#cart_items-->
```

Comment: Anyone? I need to have this done soon for my little project in school. Appreciate if there is any help :D

Answer (score 0):

Working for me here : http://62.210.240.67/hank/HNKmobile/
I'd have post a comment but apparently I need 50 pts of reputation... (not sure to understand this behaviour)

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting a site to refer. I'll reply once I able to do it. 
Does having multiple javascript cause problem? I mean I'm using a template, also I'm using the cart JS. And I couldn't see the comment you made. Do you mean that you made a comment on the post above?
But if I couldn't I hope you could let me know whats the problem I'm facing. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I was wondering if there is any source code that I can refer to, as in why mine is not working and yours are working fine and so on. Thanks.